# En java Obtener Token con solicitud POST a una URL

Tags: java, api, post

Las credenciales van en el body y en el headers poner X-Road-Client:GOB/namecliente

Este es mi codigo, pero solo retorna 500, con el postman funciona. Existe otra forma de hacerlo con java.

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Tiempo de espera de conexión agotado
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Tiempo de espera de escritura de socket
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Tiempo de espera de lectura de socket
            .build();

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

    RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("client_secret", "001MZ1J9IH039")
            .addFormDataPart("client_id", "bbbzxaki5SS0ff")
            .addFormDataPart("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://xroad-serve.gob.ar/r1/namecliente/RENAPER/LOGIN")
            .method("POST", body)
            .addHeader("X-Road-Client", "GOB/namecliente")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println("Objeto: " + response.toString());
        System.out.println("message(): " + response.message());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(V_consumo_apis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

> mensaje de salida

```
Objeto: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Server Error, url=http://xroad-serve.gob.ar/r1/namecliente/RENAPER/LOGIN}
message(): Server Error
```

Comment: ¿En postman funciona? Si funciona en postman es posible generar de manera **exacta** la petición que estás haciendo en java usando `okHttp`. En la barra lateral que hay en la derecha haz click en `</>`. Selecciona `Java - OkHttp` y prueba con el código generado por Postman. Si como dices funciona, el código generado funcionará también.

Comment: Pues ni idea qué tendrás de diferente con la petición postman que tienes _en tu terminal_. Algo estás enviando que el servidor no puede procesar (o algo no estás enviando) y por eso el servidor muere y HTTP 500. No mates al servidor y muéstranos estos mismos detalles pero en la petición postman

Comment: Estimado Jaime, exatamente es lo que realice. copie el código generado.  Esto es lo que me retorna el Postman  {
    "access_token": "hOmk75bxqiffiil4A372tgZQ",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write"
}